# Is it possible to have a counter in a form load event?

Tags: vb.net

Basically I am making a game for school, and I want to make a counter that changes its value every time the form loads. This counter is going to determine the level the user is playing.

The counter is "level":

```
dim level as integer = 0
Private Sub frmgame_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

if level = 0 then
level = 1
'run level 1 stuff
end if

if level = 1 then
level = 2
'run level 2 stuff
end if
```

When the all the enemies die, I want another form to pop up, and the current game one to disappear.

Basically the question I have is: If I load the game form again using a form.show() procedure, will it run the form load event?

How can I make it count the amount of times it loads, or shows, or whatever?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look into any of the following

- User Settings
- Saving Data to a Text File (or Database, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Make your counter `Shared` (`static` in C# and Java).  This will cause your variable to be shared across all instances of the form that ever live.

```
Private Shared level As Integer = 0

Private Sub frmgame_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    level = level + 1

End Sub
```